# If Brad didn’t agree with them, then why did he help Jordan move the money to Switzerland?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Jordan befriends his neighbor Donnie Azoff, and the two found their own company.
They bring on board several of Jordan’s friends, including Brad:

> Jordan: This is Brad. And Brad’s the guy I really wanted. But **he didn’t go along with us**.
> He was already making so much money selling Quaaludes, he’d become the Quaalude
> king of Bayside.

Later in the movie, it’s shown that Brad helped Jordan move the money to Switzerland.

If Brad didn’t agree with them, then why did he help Jordan move the money to Switzerland?

Comment: Because he's Jordan's friend. Just because he doesn't want to join in the initial scheme there's no reason he wouldn't help transfer the money... especially if he's getting a cut to do so.